# SIMPLE! no updating attributes because of wrong params, why? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, routes

i have a list of objects, under each object is a button to 'accept' or 'reject'. This button changes the 'workflow_state' attribute of the object. However, when I press the button I am left with the following error

```
param is missing or the value is empty: photo

Extracted source (around line #41):



  def params_photo
    params.require(:photo).permit!
  end

  def get_photos

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"qcFgYRM6+O7VpRo+jdVyE1OCTtHiFWpaQGJuC2qNQjw=",
 "button"=>"rejected",
 "id"=>"9"}
```

server output

```
Started PATCH "/admin/entries/9" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-13 15:05:56 +0100
Processing by Admin::EntriesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qcFgYRM6+O7VpRo+jdVyE1OCTtHiFWpaQGJuC2qNQjw=", "button"=>"rejected", "id"=>"9"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: photo):
  app/controllers/admin/entries_controller.rb:41:in `params_photo'
  app/controllers/admin/entries_controller.rb:15:in `update'
```

The objects initial state is always 'pending'. I just want a simple way to change the state but I am having a nightmare trying to achieve it. help would be greatly appreciated.

here is the relevant controller

```
class Admin::EntriesController < ApplicationController

  expose(:entries){@entries}


  def index
    @entries = Photo.with_pending_state 

  end

  def show
  end

  def update
    @entry.update_attributes(params_photo)
    if @entry.save
      return redirect_to(admin_entries_path)
    else
      return render("edit")
    end
  end



  def approved 
    @entries = Photo.with_approved_state
  end

  def pending
    @entries = Photo.with_pending_state 
  end

  def rejected
    @entries = Photo.with_rejected_state
  end


  private

  def params_photo
    params.require(:photo).permit!
  end

  def get_photos
    @entries = Entry.all
  end

end
```

the relevant view with toggle button (only one at the moment, want to get the damn thing working first!)

```
<% if entries.any? %>
  <% entries.each do |photo| %>
    <%= photo.firstname %>
    <%= image_tag photo.attachment.url %>
    <%= form_for photo, url: admin_entry_path(photo) do |t| %>
      <%= t.button :workflow_state, :value=>"rejected" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and for further clarity my routes (these things having been driving me nuts)

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :entries do
      get 'toggle_approve', :on => :member  
      collection do
        get :pending
        get :rejected
        get :approved

      end
    end
  end
```

This feels as though it should be relatively simple, yet I've been going round in circles trying to get it to work. Help is greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you log/show what you are getting for params in the update action?

Comment: Why you have your `form_for` code inside a `loop`?

Comment: @Pavan hi. I don't know, I have tried a million different things. All I want to do is toggle between three different states. I have spent hours trying to d it.

Comment: @Pavan, see this question I asked with no responses 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717592/how-to-toggle-attribute-states-in-a-view-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

**Params**

Your problem is probably due to the fact you're using the `require` method in your `strong_params`

Although this is fine & correct (`form_for` sends the params embedded within the name of the object you wish to send), it does not look like your params are doing that.

---

**Expected**

Essentially, with `strong_params`, your `require` is for the "parent" key", and the `permit` attributes are for the "child" keys. Your current method is expecting these params:

```
"params" => {
    "photo" => {
         "button" => "rejected"
     }
}
```

**Actual**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"qcFgYRM6+O7VpRo+jdVyE1OCTtHiFWpaQGJuC2qNQjw=",
 "button"=>"rejected",
 "id"=>"9"}
```

---

So when you receive the error regarding the "photo" param - it's an exception because you're *requiring* that parameter to be present, and thus if it is not, Rails can only stop.

The fix will either be to just permit the `button` param, or set the correct `form_for` method to ensure the correct params are passed):

```
params.permit(:button)
```

or

```
#app/controllers/photos_controller.rb
Class PhotosController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @photo = Photo.new
    end
end

<%= form_for @photo do |f| %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: ok I see, but that still doesn't update the params, or this that an entirely different question all togther?, I asked it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717592/how-to-toggle-attribute-states-in-a-view-in-rails  @RichPeck thanks though for your help

Comment: When you say it doesn't update the params, what do you mean? The form still sends through the same params you had before?

Comment: I am trying to update the attribute 'workflow_state', which it fails to do

Comment: Hmm okay - what about the error? Same as before, or different?